# I need Help about set value from ASP dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html-select

I have one asp dropdownlist. And I want to select value by came from client side. I can got data from client side but i can not set it my asp dropdownlist by js

***HTML***

```
<div class="col-md-6 form-group">
<asp:Label ID="ATRRegionCountryLabel" AssociatedControlID="ATRRegionCountryDropDownList" CssClass="col-sm-4 control-label" runat="server" Text="Country" />
<p class="col-sm-8">
<asp:DropDownList ID="ATRRegionCountryDropDownList" CssClass="form-control select" data-live-search="true" data-callback="hotels.aspx?cmd=city"  data-related="select-location" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
<asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="Please Select" />
</asp:DropDownList>
</p>
</div>
```

***JS***

```
$(document).on('click', '#btn-region-edit', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var $this = $(this),
id = $this.data('id'),
name = $this.data('name'),
country = $this.data('country');
$("#<%=ATRRegionCountryDropDownList.ClientID%>").val('210');            
alert(country);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I solve it like below codes

**HTML**

```
 <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
 <asp:Label ID="ATRRegionCountryLabel" 
 AssociatedControlID="ATRRegionCountryDropDownList" CssClass="col-sm-4 control-label" 
 runat="server" Text="Country" />
 <p class="col-sm-8">
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ATRRegionCountryDropDownList" CssClass="form-control select" 
 data-live-search="true" data-callback="hotels.aspx?cmd=city"  data-related="select- 
 location" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
 <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="Please Select" />
 </asp:DropDownList>
 </p>
 </div>
```

**JS**

```
 $(document).on('click', '#btn-region-edit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this),
            id = $this.data('id'),
            name = $this.data('name'),
            country = $this.data('country');            
        $('#<%=ATRRegionCountryDropDownList.ClientID %>').val(country).change();        
 });
```